# It occurs to this error when uploading file

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following form.

```
<form id="frm1" action="[host].com/api/Test/testPost" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p><input type="file" name="uploadfile" /></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

When I upload file, it always occurs to the error: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below. But if I use http://localhost:[port]/api/Test/testPost, this address can return the correct information and has no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be caused by multiple reasons. It could be due to missing document declaration. `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>`

The another way is to serialize the form into JavaScript, use formdata and ajax to upload, then you need to add the request header application/octet-stream.

Even if these are invalid, it may be related to the server. There is no testPost folder on the server or the folder permissions are not enough. This machine cannot access the remote, or it is of iis mime type.